# Increase maximum size of a string

Tags: c#, string, size, out-of-memory

I have to write a lot of data to a string, and than save it to a file.

I have made a lot of tests, and it seems that, when the file size reaches 100 mb,everything is ok, no exception is thrown.

However, if the string gets bigger, I get an out of memory exception that points to the string.

How can I increase the size limit of this string?

Comment: Would it be possible to restructure so that you don't have to have the entire string in memory at once?

Comment: Any reason you need to save it in a string first rather than writing straight to the file? It's hard to know what's wrong without more context, and ideally some code...

Comment: StringBuilder is better for Handling big strings. However this is not guaranteed to be the solution to your problems. A 100mb string all in memory is not the best thing to have around. But without knowing the purpose of your application is difficult to recommend alternatives

Comment: Do you think writing directly to a file would be faster?

Comment: As you can see, reading the analysis from Guffa below, yes, it should be faster if you don't gobble all available memory to your strings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The size limit doesn't lie in the string itself, but in how you use the memory. The only limit that the string has is the 32 bit length property which limits its size to 2 GB.

The out of memory exception doesn't come from one string being too large, it comes from having too many large strings at the same time.

I run a simple test that creates a large string by doubling itself by concatenation:

```
string x = "XXXXXXX";
while (true) {
  Console.WriteLine(x.Length);
  x = x + x;
}
```

I could create a 896 MB string before I got an exception. The exception comes when the program tries to allocate a 1.75 GB string. This demonstrates that it's not only the string itself that is causing the exception, but your total memory load.

Strings are immutable, which means that when you build up a string by concatenating strings then the string won't grow, a new string is created each time. If you don't release previously used strings (let them go out of scope or remove their reference) then they will remain in memory.

You can use a `StringBuilder` to build a string which works better than concatenating strings, but as the problem seems to be what else you have in memory I would not expect a big improvement.

You could use a `List<string>` so that you have a lot of smaller string rather than one huge string. This is similar to how the `StringBuilder` works, but it might work better with how you construct the string.

If you can write the strings directly to the file instead of first constructing the entire string, that would get rid of the memory problem. Although writing to a file is slow, the entire process may actually be somewhat faster because you only rearrange the actual work (you would do the file writing anyway), and you get rid of the work of allocating large memory areas.

If constructing the string is work intensive, you might want to look into doing the file write asynchronously. That way you would be able to work on constructing the next part of the text while you are writing to the file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.I have made several tests,and it seems using a List was the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to save all that to a file, why not just use a `FileStream` and write to it directly?

Comment: Not really am answer.

Comment: @Aron Sorry for the short answer, but I do think a `FileStream` would fit his/her needs perfectly.